# How to add Ksoap2 Jar file on IntelliJ IDEA for my android project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, ksoap2

i was doing android project on Ksoap2 webservices ,i need to add ksoap2 jar file on Intellij IDEA any body help me..

Answer (score 0):

See the [Module Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) help section.